# How to include criteria from a different model to a where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 models: `Employee` and `Vote`

```
Employee has_many votes
Vote belongs_to employee
```

The `employee` model has a `badge_number` attribute.

How can I retrieve all the votes that belong to employees with badge numbers greater than 1000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work if your `employees` table was named according to Rails conventions.

```
Vote.joins(:employee).where('employees.badge_number > 1000')
```

Since its name is `employee`, this will work:

```
Vote.joins(:employee).where('employee.badge_number > 1000')
```

Comment: Thanks. I had it as employee.badge_number and not employees.badge_number

Comment: @spuggy you mean, your table name is `employee`?

Comment: Yes. I used the singular when referring to the table. Rookie mistake

Comment: +1 For super quick answer. :) You need 1000 instead of 100 in the query.

Comment: Marek..You forgot to change `employees.badge_number` to `employee.badge_number`